# Ruby: check if object is nil

Tags: ruby

```
  def parse( line )
    _, remote_addr, status, request, size, referrer, http_user_agent, http_x_forwarded_for = /^([^\s]+) - (\d+) \"(.+)\" (\d+) \"(.*)\" \"([^\"]*)\" \"(.*)\"/.match(line).to_a

    print line
    print request
    if request && request != nil
      _, referrer_host, referrer_url = /^http[s]?:\/\/([^\/]+)(\/.*)/.match(referrer).to_a if referrer
      method, full_url, _ = request.split(' ')

in parse: private method 'split' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

So as i understand it's calling `split` not on a string, but on `nil`.
This part is parsing web server log. But I can't understand why it's getting `nil`. As I understand it's null.

Some of the subpatterns in regex failed? So it's the webserver's fault, which sometimes generates wrong logging strings?

By the way how do I write to file in ruby? I can't read properly in this cmd window under windows.

Comment: "As I understand it's null." There is no such thing as `null` in Ruby. Just `nil`.

Comment: Why what is getting nil? The function is not listed to the end, and you define several variables...

Comment: Mark i know. Amadan it's not my script mate. :) As i understand regex is throwing subpattern matches into listed variables. Like list function in php and when subpattern fails it just assign nil object to it right?

Comment: Actually, wait, it does not make any sense. Are you sure you pasted correctly? If `request` is nil as your error says, it could not have passed the `if request` guard. (BTW: `if request && request != nil` is redundant - `if request != nil` will always be `true` `if request`, which makes the latter sufficient).

Comment: Indeed. I don't know Ruby, so the statement should be different. Maybe !== instead of != should be used? I'll try that out.

Comment: Nope, it's throwing an syntax error as i understand on require. :D

Comment: Ruby's `===` is rather different from JavaScript's and PHP's `===`. This should not accomplish anything. Can you recheck what you pasted? Can you confirm there is not another `split` in your `parse` function, or that you didn't cut something out?

Comment: What syntax error on what require? There's no require in the code you pasted.

Comment: nvm it was syntax error, my bad. It throwed when ruby tried to require it. I'm not launching it directly. It's just a small parser script.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You seem to have a few questions here, so I'll take a stab at what seems to be the main one:

If you want to see if something is nil, just use `.nil?` - so in your example, you can just say `request.nil?`, which returns `true` if it is `nil` and `false` otherwise.

Comment: I'll catch request that fails and see why pattern is failing. Questiong is still opened. Why it passes statement? :)

Answer (score 10):

Ruby 2.3.0 added a *safe navigation operator* (`&.`) that checks for `nil` before calling a method.

```
request&.split(' ')
```

This is functionally* equivalent to

```
!request.nil? && request.split(' ')
```

---

*(They are slightly different. When `request` is `nil`, the top expression evaluates to `nil`, while the bottom expression evaluates to `false`.)

Answer (score 3):

To write to a file:

```
File.open("file.txt", "w") do |file|
  file.puts "whatever"
end
```

As I write in a comment above - you didn't say *what* is nil. Also, check whether `referrer` contains what you think it contains. **EDIT** I see it's request that is `nil`. Obviously, regexp trouble.

Use [rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com) to easily test your regexp. Copy a line from your input file into "Your test string", and your regexp into "Your regular expression", and tweak until you get a highlight in "Match result".

Also, what are "wrong logging strings"? If we're talking Apache, log format is configurable.

Comment: Mate... :) Why it's passing through this? if request && request != nil

Comment: Yeah, I know, I just commented on that. That should be impossible.

Comment: How to check in Ruby that some variable, in our case it's request is not an instance of nil?

Comment: `if !request.nil?` - but `if request` suffices (in Ruby, `nil` and `false` are the only values that will fail an `if`, and you can't get `false` here to confuse the issue).

Comment: btw file.txt relative to what?

Comment: Current directory. You can obviously put in a relative or absolute path as well.

Comment: Oh got it. The dir of currently used ruby script. Thanks +1 :)

Comment: No, the current directory. If you are located in `/path/to/my/prompt` but start your script with `/path/to/my/script.rb`, then it will write the file as `/path/to/my/prompt/file.txt`. It will only write in the directory of the ruby script if you're there as well.

Comment: I i'll write failing request into file. What i'll see there? An empty space?

Comment: Use `file.puts request.inspect` instead of `file.puts request` - easier to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks. I'v got another error and this is written in a file "- " hmmm

Comment: Dumped this problem log string "89.254.137.55 - 400 \"-\" 0 \"-\" \"-\" \"-\"\n" it's contents of line variable which is passed into regex. Hmm

Comment: So it fails only when 400 header is in a log. I have added && status!=400 in a statement. But i need to log 400 headers as well...

Comment: Got it. It's because "-" can't be split by space, because there is no whitespace in there. So i'll have to add request!='-' in the statement or change subpattern to match \"([^-]+)\" question is closed i think ;) I'll check it though. And what it is btw 200.144.5.8 - 400 "№Пьd\x1Dро’~,zНм\x05TvХ\x22\x1F3" 166 "-" "-" "-" ? O_o