# undefined method text for NilClass

Tags: ruby

I have a simple crawler written in Ruby that should crawl specific site and save data into a CSV file. When I am trying to run the script, I keep getting undefined method error :

```
boxers.rb:29:in `<main>': undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

This is the code of script I'm trying to run:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'csv'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new{ |agent| agent.history.max_size=0 }
agent.user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0'

base = "http://siteurl.com/"

division = ARGV[0]

search_url = "http://siteurl.com/ratings.php?sex=M&division=#{division}&pageID="

path='//*[@id="mainContent"]/table/tr[position()>2]'

boxers = CSV.open("csv/file.csv","w")

url = search_url+"1"

begin
  page = agent.get(url)
rescue
  print "  -> error, retrying\n"
  retry
end

// propably the line that causes error
a = page.parser.xpath('//a[@title="last page"]').first.text
a.gsub!("[","")
a.gsub!("]","")

last = a.to_i

(1..last).each do |page|

  url = search_url+page.to_s

  begin
    page = agent.get(url)
  rescue
    print "  -> error, retrying\n"
    retry
  end

  page.parser.xpath(path).each do |tr|
    row = [division]
    tr.xpath("td").each_with_index do |td,j|
      case j
      when 0,11
        next
      when 2
        text = td.text.strip
        a = td.xpath("a").first
        href = base+a.attributes["href"].value.strip
        human_id = href.split("=")[1].split("&")[0]
        cat = href.split("=")[2]
        row += [human_id, cat, text, href]
      when 4
        text = td.text.strip
        record = text.split("-")
        wins = record[0]
        wko = wins.split("(")[1].split(")")[0] rescue 0
        wins = wins.split("(")[0]
        losses = record[1]
        lko = losses.split("(")[1].split(")")[0] rescue 0
        losses = losses.split("(")[0]
        draws = record[2]
        row += [wins, wko, losses, lko, draws, text]
      when 5
        last6 = []
        td.xpath("table/tr/td").each do |td2|
          outcome = td2.attributes["class"].value.strip rescue nil
          last6 += [outcome]
        end
        last6 = last6.to_s.gsub("[","{").gsub("]","}")
        row += [last6]
      when 9
        div = td.xpath("div").first
        flag = div.attributes["class"].value.strip rescue nil
        title = div.attributes["title"].value.strip rescue nil
        row += [flag,title]
      else
        text = td.text.strip
        row += [text]
      end
    end
    if (row.size>2)
      boxers << row
    end
  end
  boxers.flush

end

boxers.close
```

Comment: can you comment the line at which the error is raised ?

Comment: Added comment for the line that should be causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `.text` on something that has no value, or `nil`.

Based on the error message, it's on line 29, which makes me beleive this line is the culprit:

```
a = page.parser.xpath('//a[@title="last page"]').first.text
```

It looks like when `xpath(...)` doesn't match on any elements, it returns an empty enumeration. So `first` can't find anything, so it returns nil.

The solution is to check for `nil`. There is a lot of guidance and resource for checking for nil in Ruby, such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143652/ruby-check-if-object-is-nil).

Comment: by the way did you notice that OP is accessing this url : http://siteurl.com/ratings.php?sex=M&division=#{division}&pageID=1 from his code but the url returns 404 ;)

Comment: I assume the OP changed the URL in the question to mask the actual page being scraped.